# PDF low quality when printing an image

Tags: windows, pdf, microsoft-paint

When I edit an image in Paint and save it as a PDF file, the PDF document doesn't have a high quality.

### Sample image

[image]

### Sample PDF

[image]
Any suggestions?

P.S. This is actually how I tried to edit a PDF document. Steps to reproduce the issue:

- Open [the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MNgy7OCIAcJ8Z3tCm04pvbyrCX8bdZTl/view?usp=sharing) in Chrome.
- Take a screenshot.
- Paste it in Paint.
- Edit  the form.
- Print it as a PDF.

The result is no similar to the original PDF.

Comment: Can you give an example of the resolution difference when the image was saved in Paint then to PDF?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: Done.

Comment: Most created PDF files use internally JPEG algorithm for saving mages. For high-contrast images like text on white background JPEG is a bad choice. Better to use an PDF editor, then you don't need to convert the PDF file to an image and the quality does not drop.

Comment: I am not familiar with MS Paint, but what you will have to do is make sure that your resolution is sufficient (we talk about 300 ppi). However, as @Robert states, use a PDF editor; Acrobat Reader would be the tool of choice, and fill the form with Text comments. (even better would be to persuade the owner of the form to make it fillable).

Comment: @Robert: Please post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most created PDF files use internally JPEG algorithm for saving mages. For high-contrast images like text on white background JPEG is a bad choice but standard "Print-to-PDF" systems do not allow to configure this and always use JEP as image format.

Therefore I would recommend to use an PDF editor, then you don't need to convert the PDF file to an image and the quality does not drop.

Try for example Adobe Acrobat Reader DC if the PDF contains editable form fields, otherwise on of the free PDF editors should be fine.